# SSRS reporting expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

How to write expresion to subtract 1 minute from original value in column

eg original in column is =Fields!end_date.Value,
then want to subtract 1 minute from original value,

Anybody can asnwer my question?

Comment: Lookup the .NET DateTime class and its methods.

Comment: SSRS Expressions support `DateAdd`. When you're in the expression editor, the list of Date and Time datatypes, with their descriptions and Examples, should be *all* the information you need.

Comment: @bradbury9 you can also call DateTime methods as defined in .NET as iamdave shows with `AddMinutes`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I didnt know that was introduced in SSRS @DaleK

Answer (score 0):

You do need to check the [SSRS date related functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expression-examples-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15#DateFunctions), you will see one named `DateAdd` that fits your need.

It should be something similar to:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Minute, -1, Fields!end_date.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @bradbury9's answer, you can also use date arithmetic similar to that found in .Net, assuming your data is of a suitable data type, for example:

```
=Fields!end_date.Value.AddMinutes(1)
=Fields!end_date.Value.AddDays(-Today.Day).AddMinutes(1)
```

etc